# Requiring pry gem into ruby script causes error

Tags: ruby, pry

I am using ruby version `2.3.3p222`

Here is my Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'pry'
```

I run `bundle` and here is the resulting `Gemfile.lock`

```
Gemfile.lock
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    coderay (1.1.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    pry (0.12.2)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.9.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  pry

BUNDLED WITH
   1.15.1
```

I then simply run a ruby script via `ruby my_report.rb` (this script is located in the same directory as `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`).  `my_report.rb` only has this in the file:

```
require 'pry'
```

Here is the error:

```
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/pry-rescue-1.4.5/lib/pry-rescue.rb:15: warning: method BaseHelpers#windows? is deprecated. Use Pry:Helpers::Platform.windows? instead
/Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/pry-stack_explorer-0.4.9.2/lib/pry-stack_explorer.rb:128:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `before_command' for #<Pry::CommandSet:0x007fccdcf0b1e8> (NoMethodError)
```

**Question:** What am I missing? How can I properly require in `pry` into my ruby script so that I can set breakpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually worked for me is I just uninstalled all of the `pry` versions I had installed via `gem uninstall`.  Then: in my gemfile I specified a previous version of `0.11.3`:

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'pry', '0.11.3'
```

I did `bundle install` and then ran my ruby script, and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and FWIW upgrading pry to the latest version fixed it for me.

```rb
# Gemfile
gem 'pry', '~> 0.14.2'
```